# Is there anyway to open/show a div after the page has reloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to open a modal window after a page is reloaded.I am planning to open that modal inside a div.So is there any way to open a div after the page has been loaded?

Comment: You will need to build a system to know whether the user has visited the page before or not. There's no other way to know fi this page load was the first time, or subsequent refresh. I'd suggest using cookies or localStorage.

Comment: how can we we reload and open a div simultaneously using settimeout()?

Comment: Is it first time load or everytime when the page is reloaded?

Comment: everytime the page is reloaded.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without using any event handlers" when you've tagged this `jquery`.    If you want to know if it's a load vs reload, use `performance.navigation.type`

Answer (score 0):

if you wont to do it with only javascript , you can by using **url hash parameters** .

The **idea** is when page first load **js** will add a word to URL ,So when the page reload again **js** will see the word in url so we will know that the page is reloaded and how many time.

**like**:

```js
var url = window.location.href;
var hash = url.split('#')[1];
var recount;
if(hash != null){
recount = parseInt(hash.split('-')[1])+1;
hash = hash.split('-')[0];
}
if (hash == "re") {
 var elm = document.getElementById("first");
 elm.innerHTML = "the page has been reloaded ("+recount+")";
    window.location.href = url.split('#')[0] + "#re-"+recount;
//alert("the page has been reloaded ("+recount+")");
} else {
    window.location.href += "#re-0";
}
```

```html
<body>
 <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>
 <div id ="first">first page</div>
</body>
```

**After** add **bootstrap** and **jquery**

```js
var url = window.location.href;
var hash = url.split('#')[1];
var recount;
if(hash != null){
recount = parseInt(hash.split('-')[1])+1;
hash = hash.split('-')[0];
}
if (hash == "re") {
 $("#first").hide();
 $("#modal_text").html("the page has been reloaded ("+recount+")");
 $("#myModal").modal();
    window.location.href = url.split('#')[0] + "#re-"+recount;
    
} else {
    window.location.href += "#re-0";
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>
 <div id ="first"><h1>first page</h1></div>
 <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
     
       <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <p id='modal_text'></p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </div>
       
     </div>
   </div>
   

</body>
```

but I **suggest** using cookies or localStorage for **best way** .